# XCode 4 storyboard

Tags: storyboard, save, xcode4, textfield

I have created a tableview in storyboard.
I want to add a favourite button on the right hand top corner in the 'Title bar'
when the button is pressed it will link to the tableview that is created earlier. The data that I want needs to be saved and when the app is relaunched, the data is still stored inside the tableview cell. In the tableview, the data can be edited with another 'edit' button on the top left hand corner at the 'Title bar'.  I have looked for pList saving tutorials, but some were quite old. E.G. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0DAoMl79b1A

Anyone have codes/tutorial for it ?